# Rails Console Deletion using Where Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rail app from Rails Console I want to delete Customers whose creater_id = some id like bellow:

```
Customer.where(creater_id: 5).delete_all
```

What is the **best method** *( As rails offers different ways for same task I am curious to know about any other way to implement the same with more optimized in  performance wise and impact on DB*) to delete using rails condition based on a specific condition using "where" ?

Comment: What is the problem with the current query?

Comment: Hey you can used `Customer.where(creater_id: 5).destroy_all` it will delete all dependent child object also.

Comment: @Pavan Just wanted to know as Rails offers different ways for same task that, If there any better or more optimized way to do the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This totally depends on what you really want to do:

- `delete_all` is a faster method as compare to `destroy_all`, because delete does not check for dependents. It will only delete rows of single table on which it is being called.
- `destroy_all` is used when we want to delete all the dependents of the model too.

E.g if `Student` has many `courses`.

- Calling `User.where(some: 'some').delete_all` will delete all the users but association of the student with courses will still be there in a association table.
- Calling `User.where(some: 'some').destroy_all` will delete all the users along with courses association.